# ScaleTimeRange of only a part of video

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

The `scaleTimeRange(timeRange: CMTimeRange, toDuration duration: CMTime)` method works very well if one wants to apply Slow motion effect to video.

But I noticed that it *only works if applied to the entire video*'s duration. If an arbitrary timeRange, e.g. a `CMTimeRangeMake(_ start: 2, duration: 3)` is passed , the method doesn't seem to work at all. i.e. When the mp4 video is exported it doesn't have the desired slow motion effect (from 0:00:02 - 0:00:05)

**Q 1**) Is there a way to apply this `scaleTimeRange` method to only a part of the video? If so, how can it be done?

**Q2**)If not , how can this slow motion effect be applied to only a part of the video? Is there any other way?

**CODE** :

```
var asset: AVAsset?


func  setupAsset(){

let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sample", withExtension: "mp4")!)

let comp = AVMutableComposition()

let videoAssetSourceTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first! as AVAssetTrack


let videoCompositionTrack = comp.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)


do {

    try videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(
        CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(9 , 600)),
        of: videoAssetSourceTrack,
        at: kCMTimeZero)


    let videoScaleFactor = Int64(3.0)
    let videoDuration: CMTime = videoAsset.duration



    let tstStartTime = CMTime(value: 2, timescale: videoDuration.timescale)
    let tstDuration =  CMTime(value: 1 , timescale: videoDuration.timescale)

    //1.  Applies slow motion correctly (to entire video)

    videoCompositionTrack.scaleTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero , videoDuration), toDuration: CMTimeMake(videoDuration.value * videoScaleFactor, videoDuration.timescale))

    //2. Replace with 1 , the exported video plays as is with no slow motion effect

    videoCompositionTrack.scaleTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero , tstDuration), toDuration: CMTimeMake(tstDuration.value * videoScaleFactor, videoDuration.timescale))

    // 3. Replace with 1, unexpected behaviour : video only displays first frame for CMTimeMakes's value then proceeds to play video normally.
    videoCompositionTrack.scaleTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(tstStartTime , tstDuration), toDuration: CMTimeMake(tstDuration.value * videoScaleFactor, videoDuration.timescale))



     videoCompositionTrack.preferredTransform = videoAssetSourceTrack.preferredTransform



}catch { print(error) }

asset = comp
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the isue " the method doesn't seem to work at all"?

Comment: The video is saved successfully , however there is no slow motion effect. 
The exported mp4 file is identical to the source mp4 file , with the same frame rate.

Comment: What is `CMTime`s value? Can you post relevant code please?

Comment: I updated the question. Please have a look .

Comment: If you have done this please share the code or tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's working "correctly", but the portion of the video that you are slowing down is much, much smaller than you expect.

`CMTime` is a very unusual data structure, so it can be very confusing to wrap your head around it. What is the value of `videoDuration.timescale` that you are using to construct the `tstStartTime` and `tstDuration` variables? The larger that timescale value is, the smaller the portion of time that is represented by the `CMTime` value.

For example, if the timescale is 4, then `CMTime(value: 2, timescale: 4)` represents `2/4` seconds, or half a second.

For more information, see the documentation for `CMTime`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremedia/1669288-cmtime

Comment: The value of `videoDuration.timescale` is 600. I have a slight idea of what the `timeScale` does , but I have seen code where  it's value is `90000` , and that is very confusing , because I don't know why such a high value is necessary.
This is from apple's StopNGo sample app
`frameDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds = CMTimeMake(1.0/5/0 , 90000)`    //5fps  - taking five pictures will equal 1 sec of video.

Comment: I'm not sure of the specific reason why they chose a timescale of 90000 for that sample, but the reason why CMTime works the way it does is to enable extremely high precision across a wide range with no rounding error. Here's a blog post that attempts to explain it in more depth: https://warrenmoore.net/understanding-cmtime

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. My assumption was that `scaleTimeRange` could only be used for the entire video and not a segment but perhaps I need to deepen my understanding of `CMTime`.